# Does „enforce cHash for uncached extbase actions“ lead to additional cache entries?

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase

With [78002](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78002-) even uncached extbase actions generate a cHash.

But a valid cHash used to (?) always generate a cache entry.

Can anybody explain the context and how the system knows not to create a cache entry in this case? Or is a cache entry created but just the plugins output stays uncached?